# Data transfer between two linux servers

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to transfer data between two linux servers using the ssh connection to the servers, using specific scripts, and using direct cross-over cable. The two servers have multiple network interfaces; the interface 1 (eth0) of both servers are connected to a switch and go online (with IP 192.168.xx.1 (server 1) and 192.168.xx.2 (server2)).

I connected a crossover cable directly between the two servers, on the eth1 interfaces of both, with IP address of the type 192.168.yy.1 (server 1) and 192.168.yy.2 (server 2). When I start the data transfer script I have to enter the target IP address (server 2), and insert 192.168.xx.2.

But will the actual data transfer be via the crossover cable? Will the fastest route in the routing table be used automatically?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the IP addresses assigned to the interface with the crossover cable, this interface will be used.

The `link local` route for the subnet is always the preferred route.

Comment: So even if I insert the ip: 192.168.xx.2, will the fastest one be used for the transfer (192.168.yy.2)?

Comment: No, only if you use the IP's on the crossover interfaces. There is no way for the systems to known, that there are other ways to reach the target system

Answer (score 1):

If you use the target address 192.168.xx.2, your interface eth0 will be used.

If you use the target address 192.168.yy.2, your interface eth1 will be used.

As you have to specify the address anyway, why not use the 192.168.yy.2 address?

Form the systems' point of view, there is no difference between the two connections, the switch on eth0 is transparent. The switch also doesn't add a big delay.

If you really want to use the address 192.168.xx.2 through the cable at eth1, you need some specific routing on both sides. Are you sure the complication is worth it?

```
ip route add 192.168.xx.2/32 src 192.168.xx.1 via 192.168.yy.2
```